# Reselect selectors structure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reselect

i have the following example structure..

```
userId: {
  savedEvents: {
     eventId: true,
     eventId: true,
     eventId: true,
  },
  organisedEvents: {
     eventId: true,
     eventId: true,
     eventId: true,
  },
  attendingEvents: {
     eventId: true,
     eventId: true,
     eventId: true,
  }
}
```

I am using reselects createSelector method to try and chain selectors for memory optimisations and re-use of business logic..

**For example :-**

```
userOrganisedEventsSelector
```

Returns a list of organised event ids.

```
activeUserOrganisedEventsSelector
```

Uses the output of userOrganisedEventsSelector with a set of filters have been applied

```
sortedActiveUserOrganisedEventsSelector
```

Sorts the output of activeUserOrganisedEventsSelector

The three above methods accept a prop object containing userId, from which it can then determine the organised event.

**The problem :-**

1. I want the same functionality for all three event types (savedEvents, organisedEvents and attendingEvents)
2. In some scenarios i would like the userId to be provided by props, other times i need to use a userId from state.

I am looking for help or advise on how to achieve this, without creating 30 odd functions, while keeping the benefits of memorising via reselect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you to give [re-reselect](https://github.com/toomuchdesign/re-reselect) a try. It's a tiny `reselect` wrapper I wrote when I found my self writing almost identical selectors in a scenario similar to yours.

It will allow you to not repeat selectors code and to better manage selectors caching when passing different params (eg, your `userID`).

Here a few line of pseudocode, just you get you on the right track:

```
import createSelector from 'reselect';
import createCachedSelector from 're-reselect';

// Normal reselect selector:
// getUserEvents(state, userId)
const getUserEvents = createSelector(
  state => state.events
  (state, userId) => userId,            // Get user from state if userId not provided
  (events, userId) => events[userId],   // Return user's events
);

// Cached re-reselect selector (cached by eventType):
// getUserEventsOfType(state, userId, eventType = 'ALL')
const getUserEventsOfType = createCachedSelector(
  getUserEvents,                        // Get events from getUserEvents
  (state, userId, eventType = 'ALL') => eventType,
  (userEvents, eventType) => userEvents[eventType]  // Just pseudo code!
)(
  // Keep memoization when calling selector with different eventType
  (state, userId, eventType = 'ALL') => eventType,
);
```

Comment: As it happens, i had stumbled onto your lib this morning also. Thanks for the example and the library.

Comment: I have tried the rereselect library. One doubt I got. for selectorA, if we used userid as a cache key, can I use userid as a key for selectorB?